# Do Adrenaline and Hope stack?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

I want to know if these 2 perks stack their haste effects to know if other perks in the future will be able to stack haste as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the wiki it looks like Hope and Adrenaline can't stack. Adrenaline is activated  as soon as the last generator is completed while Hope isn't activated until an Exit Gate is opened.

Unless Hope activates once the hatch closes like Adrenaline does I don't think that these perks have a chance to stack, but if they do then they definitely can stack. You can use any other exhaustion perk and get a speed boost while Hope is activated and get both haste status effects as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the perk description for Hope. It says it activates "once the exit gates are powered", not once they are opened. The exit gates are powered once all gens are done, so that you can then open them with the switch. Hope activates as soon as all generators are done, same as Adrenaline, and so they probably stack. It's hard to tell if they really do, because Adrenaline sets the movement speed to 150% and Hope would only add another 7%, but theoretically the Haste buff should stack.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is if you can use both skills at the same time, the answer is yes, but ten in mind that it is only activated, once the exit doors are open.